# ASP.NET form name

Tags: asp.net, forms

From what I understand, the id of the master  on an ASP.NET page is "aspnetForm". I noticed today that for some reason in one of our pages it's now "form1". What would cause this change? Where should I look for the root cause of this naming change? We've got a lot of JavaScript variables that (sign) reference "aspnetForm" that are now broken.

Comment: Does your source control provider (assuming you use source control) have a 'blame' facility?  If so, use this tool on the file to find out when the change was introduced.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that the form isn't explicitly named somewhere (e.g. id=form1)?